# Numpy apply where operation to specific index range of an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an 2000X3000 binary rgb image, i want to get the number of pixels that match certain color (say blue(0,0,255)) on a given coordinate points ((x,y)(xmax,ymax)).

I know how to calculate for the whole image using np masks, but not sure how to do this on only a certain range of an array

Comment: First slice the image array: `img[x:xmax, y:ymax]`, then operate on the slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your array and check:

```
if (part_of_array == blue).all():
    number_of_blue_pixels += 1
```

`All ()` returns true when all values are equal.